# How to select text with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I select a part of the text and process by jQuery? For example, I have a text as

```
<div id="test">This is an example text here</div>
```

I select few words (not the whole div) with mouse, and want to show these words (part of `#test`) in

```
<div id="target"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how. The following works in all major browsers, including IE 6.

```
function getSelectedText() {
    var selectedText = "", sel;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        selectedText = "" + window.getSelection();
    } else if ( (sel = document.selection) && sel.type == "Text") {
        selectedText = sel.createRange().text;
    }
    return selectedText;
}

$('#target').text( getSelectedText() );
```

Answer (score 6):

If you mean by select text then show it into an element.

```
var selectedText;

if(window.getSelection)
{
    selectedText = window.getSelection();
}
else if(document.getSelection)
{
    selectedText = document.getSelection();
}
else if(document.selection)
{
    selectedText = document.selection.createRange();
}

$('#target').text(selectedText.toString());
```

Or by typical showing an element text into another element, then you use:

```
$('#target').text($('#test').text());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [text method](http://api.jquery.com/text/) like so:

```
(function(namespace) {
  namespace.getSelected = function() {
    var t = '';
    if (window.getSelection) {
        t = window.getSelection();
    } else if (document.getSelection) {
        t = document.getSelection();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        t = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return t;
  };
}(Namespace || {}))

$(function() {
  $('#test').on("mouseup", function() {
    var selectedText = Namespace.getSelected();
    if (selectedText) {
      $('#target').text(selectedText);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Where is the user selected text taken in account?

Comment: How you will get the currently selected text ?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer

http://mark.koli.ch/2009/09/use-javascript-and-jquery-to-get-user-selected-text.html

Answer (score 1):

```
$.fn.selectRange = function(start, end) {
    return this.each(function() {
        if(this.setSelectionRange) {
            this.focus();
            this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
        } else if(this.createTextRange) {
            var range = this.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', end);
            range.moveStart('character', start);
            range.select();
        }
    });
};
```

Reference: http://programanddesign.com/js/jquery-select-text-range/

Comment: That only applies to text inputs and textareas. The question is about selections in regular HTML content. Also, I think the OP wants to get the selected text rather than set it.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use http://www.examplet.buss.hk/jquery/caret.php plugin and you could easily get the selected text

// Get start pos in intput box with id="box1"
$("#box1").caret().start

// Get end pos
$("#box1").caret().end

// Get selected text
$("#box1").caret().text

Comment: That only applies to text inputs and textareas. The question is about selections in regular HTML content.