# Return selected text JS (no JQuery)

Tags: textselection

I need to get the selected text on a document without using JQuery. Is there a way i can like do `document.selectedtext` or something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251937/how-to-get-selecteduser-highlighted-text-in-contenteditable-element-and-replac

Comment: That uses Jquery. I specifically said no JQuery.

Comment: First and accepted answer doesn't use jquery at all. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6252212/722135

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8713757/96100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.getSelection();
```

U'll need to turn it into a string after that.

Comment: It's `window.getSelection()`, not `window.getSelected()`.